# All the data are not retrieved from a field in mysql

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-5

I am using summernote in my laravel project. Since, summernote encodes images into base64 during storage. But, the main problem is that when i query to get encoded image data. Then, i don't get base64 encoded image data.

**Data_In_MysQL_Database:**
[here](http://pastebin.com/Vd41Muw6)

**Query_used_in_Laravel:**

```
$exhibitors = DB::table('exhibitors')->select('description')->get();
```

Any help will be appreciated!!

Thanks

Comment: "i don't get base64 encoded image data." What do you get then? You say that your pastebin shows us the data as it appears in the database. How does that compare with the data you get from the laravel query?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

During querying database, i got only paragraph stored from the editor and i did not get base64 encoded image data, the problem was that i had not the sufficient space to store base64 encoded image data in the database's column.

Problem solved by just changing my database field from `TEXT` to `LONGTEXT`.

Anyway thanks.